# Using functions from my website in chrome console or firefox console?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a webpage up and running that has two js files with a bunch of functions. My HTML code loads these scripts as modules on startup. Problem is that i have a function called "showAdminTools()" and im afraid that this functions perhaps can be accessed through the chrome dev tools by non admins?

Comment: Every time i try to access the showAdminTools() function in the chrome console i get errors that the function is not defined, does this mean its impossible to access it or does it mean im doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes everyone can access them with the console.

Comment: can you give me an example of how you would access it? when i type "showAdminTools()" in console i get an error

Comment: i basically have a js file that has a function called showAdminTools(); for instance: function showAdminTools(){ do stuff };

Comment: and i get error in browser console if i try to call it with "showAdminTools()"

Answer (score 2):

If the user isn't an admin, then don't send anything to their browser which should only be available to admins.

If the script is sensitive, then put it behind Authn/Authz and don't include it in a `<script>` if the user isn't an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Actually im stupid, i already have server side code that prevents requests from client unless the user already is admin, so it does not matter if they can go into admin tools or not, any request from the admin tools page will be denied by server...

SORRY FOR WASTING TIME